# Laravel validation: unique, when name is equal, but other field is different

Tags: validation, laravel, unique, laravel-5.1

Tags can have the same name, when their value `modul_id` is differnet.
Currently I use this piece of code:

```
$tag = Tag::firstOrNew([
    'name' => $request->get('name'),
    'modul_id' => Modul::where('short', $modul_short)->first()->id
]);

if(!$tag->id) {
  $tag->save(); //this is a new entry

} else {
  //record was allready there
}
```

Is it possible to make a validation rule for "you can have the same name, but then you need a different modul_id" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Laravel Validator and the unique validation rule:

```
 $module_id = $request->get('module_id');
 $rules = [
     'name' => 'unique:tags,name,NULL,id,modul_id,'.$module_id
 ]
```

This assumes, that the module_id is provided with the request (Or fetched somehow else before validating.

The example means, that an unique check is performed for the table 'tags' on the column 'name', but this check is only run on the rows that do match given $module_id.

For more info you can have a look at [Laravel Docs - Unique Validation rule](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique)

Comment: worked, but is there any way to put this into the request class?

Comment: You mean inside a Form Request Validation ?

Comment: Yeah, i would prefer to serparate the validation and the controller.

Comment: This should work with that, too. Where are you having trouble ?

Comment: To get the value `$module_id` from the url.

Comment: this should work with $this->request->get('module_id') within your rules function.

Comment: `$this->request->get('module_id')` doesn't work, but `\Route::input('modul_id')` works great :)

Comment: You can use $this->module_id in Form Request Class